# I want to create a responsive grid using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid

I want to create a grid like this,

[image: Picture of the image grid]

It should be responsive, I'm using bootstrap 3. Is there any way I could code this up. I tried different column combinations and trying to adjust margins and padding. 
But not actually working with it.

Comment: Any sample project or fiddle would be really helpful.

Comment: Masonry. The answer to pictures like this is always Masonry.

Comment: Thanks, I'm taking a look at masonry.